# document.getElementById not working on jquery load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've loaded an  html file with jquery `load` function

in my **profile.blade.php**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#newJob").load('/company/new-job');
      });
    </script>
   <script src="js/location.js"></script>
```

in my `location.js`  i am  using

`document.getElementById('autocomplete')` for getting an html element

but this element is in `company/new-job` file

the problem i got undefined error in `document.getElementById('autocomplete')` this part

when i directly include the `location.js` its working fine

Comment: What do you mean by "directly including the `location.js`"

Comment: Could you please elaborate **when i directly include the location.js its working fine**? Also, could you post necessary `location.js` contents?

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala it means all the contents of `location.js` lncluded in an inline script

Comment: May I know whether you are using your `<script>` tag inside the `<head>` tag? If yes, please insert the `<script>` tag just before the `</body>` tag. Also be sure to load the `location.js` before your other script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `load`'s callback function to insert the script you wish:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newJob").load('/company/new-job', null, function(){
        $.getScript('js/location.js');
    });
});
```

Comment: let me try your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `location.js` in the html page returning from `/company/new-job` to get it work.

Or try loading the js like below. (not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#newJob").load('/company/new-job',function(data){
     //here you can get the elements from /company/new-job.
       $.getScript('js/location.js').done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
          //here you can call functions from location.js
       });         
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your script  `<script src="js/location.js"></script>` load before [$(document).ready(function()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and your element will load after document is ready and .load mehtod.

So here need to do is that have to add your script after your element render. otherwise  `document.getElementById('autocomplete')` cant't find element and generate error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#newJob").load("/company/new-job", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
           $.getScript('js/location.js');
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
});
```