# JQuery : Stop refresh with ClearInterval once an element appears

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Pretty new to Javascript, I'm trying to do the following thing :
I'm using a Flask app, and when I go on one page, it shows different information coming from my MySQL db.
But in the meantime, as one task is longer than other, I've it running in background, allowing the page to be displayed before this task finishes.
So on my page, I've a button which appears in disabled mode, with a message displaying that it will arrive.
So I've succeeded to refresh the div part including this button, meaning that when the background tasks ends, the button's mode changes and becomes clickable.

On the Javascript side, I'm using the SetInterval function to refresh the div each 3 seconds, and it loads a second page, with the only the code I want for that part of my page.

But my point here is to be able to stop the refresh once the button become active.
I've seen that we can do that using the ClearInterval and looking if an HTML element appears.
But it doesn't work, and the refresh still continue even when my new button appears.

Here's the code I'm using :

page.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myDiv').load("page2.html");
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('mybutton') != null) {
        clearInterval(interval)
                    }
    else {
        $('#myDiv').load("page2.html");
        }
    },3000);
});
...........
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

pag2.html

```
{% set results = task_id|values %}
{% if not results %}
<button type="button" class="btn disabled btn-light">Please wait</button>
{% else %}
<button id="mybutton" type="button" class="btn  btn-primary">Click</button>
{% endif %}
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449885/document-getelementbyid-not-working-on-jquery-load

Answer (score 0):

JQuery load() function has a callback function , you can do whatever you need there after the load is comleted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    loadDiv();
    function loadDiv() {
        $('#myDiv').load("page2.html", loaded);     
    }      

    function loaded(response, status, codes) {         
        if(status === 'error') {             
            loadDiv();         
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this ?
`$(document).ready(function() {
                    $(‘#myDiv’).load("page2.html");
                    var interval;
                    interval = setInterval(function() {
                            $('#myDiv').load(“page2.html”, "", function() {
                                if (document.getElementById(‘myButton’) != null) {
                                    clearInterval(interval)
                            }});
                    },3000);
                });`
I've tried it, but still reloads even when the button appears on the page.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    loadDiv();
    function loadDiv() {
        $('#myDiv').load("page2.html", loaded);
    }

    function loaded(response, status, codes) {
        if(status === 'error') {
            loadDiv();
        }
    }
});`

Comment: 1. Added a function to load the div (loadDiv),
2. Calling the function initially.(loadDiv),
3. loadDiv calls a callback function once loaded,
4. callback function checks for the response.
5. if not loaded, then calls loadDiv again

Comment: Hi all, It finally worked as expected, thanks to your support. The last thing I had to do to make it works, is also to monitor for the button value. If this is not the message which is presented while job is running anymore, loadDiv is runned one more time, etc...
Thanks again